# Receiving a shared file

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have a problem with reception a `.txt` file in this case by whats'app.
I get the intent in my activity:

```
//check intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();
```

control if it is an `ACTION_SEND`, extract `extra` through a `Bundle`, create a new `File` and try to transform it into a `String`:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && Objects.equals (type, "text/plain")) {
    Log.d ("Intent", "have shared");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras ();
    Uri uri = (Uri) bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    Log.d ("uri ",
    uri.getAuthority ()+" "+
    uri.getPath ()+" "+
    uri.getFragment ()+" "+
    uri.getUserInfo ());
    File file = new File (uri.getPath ());
    Log.d("file" , file.toString ()+" "+file.getPath ()+" "+file.getName ()+" "+ file.exists ()+" "+ file.isFile ()+" "+file.isDirectory ()+" "+file.isAbsolute ()+" "+file.isHidden ());
    try {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        //read line by line
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             text.append(line);
             text.append('\n');
        }
        Log.d ("String", text.toString ());
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace ();
        }
```

The result of the debug logs are:

```
D/uri: com.whatsapp.provider.media /item/95 null null
D/file: /item/95 /item/95 95 false false false true false
```

I get this error on `BufferedReader`:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /item/95: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And I do not understand why.
can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not being given a path to a file. You are being given a `Uri`. A `Uri` is not a file, and your `Uri` specifically has a `content` scheme, not a `file` scheme.

Remove `File file = new File (uri.getPath ());`. Replace `new FileReader(file)` with `new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri))`, to handle both `content` and `file` schemes.