# How to get the filename of a shared WhatsApp text file in Xamarin Forms Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-intent, shared-file

I used to use the following method to get the name of a text file shared via **WhatsApp** to my app:

```
string GetIntentFilename(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    string filename;
    string temp;

    using (var c1 = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
    {
        c1.MoveToFirst();
        temp = c1.GetString(0);

        filename = temp.Substring(temp.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    }

    return filename.Trim();
}
```

If I shared a file **123.txt**, the above method would return **"123.txt"**

Recently however it has been returning me a weird name, similar to the following: **"DOC-20230109-WA0008."**

I've tried sharing the file with other apps and they successfully extract the **123.txt** filename, so I'm sure the information exists somewhere in the intent, but I don't know how to get it.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried examining the other properties of the `Query` result in the debugger?

Comment: Hi Jason, yes, nothing I can see. The return type is **ICursor**, which has 2 columns: displayname and size. The first column returns the above name, the second an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer about [Android Studio get shared file, name of Uri, from whatsapp to my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73309117/android-studio-get-shared-file-name-of-uri-from-whatsapp-to-my-app), you can try the following code:

```
string GetIntentFilename(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    string filename;

    using (var c1 = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
    {
     //  var index = c1.GetColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DisplayName);

     //  the OpenableColumns.DisplayName has been deprecated, you can try the next line code

       var index = c1.GetColumnIndex(IOpenableColumns.DisplayName);
       c1.MoveToFirst();
       filename = c1.GetString(index);
                }
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: Hi Liyun, just tried your code, thanks for that. It returns the exact same strange filename as my code above.

Comment: How did you get the uri when you receive the file? @jho

Comment: `Uri GetIntentUri() { return (Uri)Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream); }`

Comment: You can try [this method about receiving a file from whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849388/receiving-a-shared-file). @jho

Comment: I've just read that code. The solution tells how to get the inputstream from the Intent. It doesn't discuss the filename issue.

Comment: You can try to receive the shared file with answer's code and set the file name.

Comment: I want to receive the file together with its filename, not set the filename.

Comment: You can try to debug to check the intent or the Uri.